# receive all public hostnames in a bind (linux) server

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I need to save all public hostnames, that usually can be detected with a dns query, in my dns server (bind9 in a kubuntu distribution), and after I need to open this list to elaborate it in a c++ program.

How is it possible to do this saving operation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use host or dig command to run axfr query and redirect output to file:

```
host -t axfr yourdomain.com > records.txt
```

or

```
dig yourdomain.com axfr > records.txt
```

You can do this directly in dns server or any other host that has Bind's permission to do so.
Note that you have to have tcp port 53 open to your dns server if you use external host to run query.